# Syntax check for JavaScript using command

Tags: javascript, node.js

Are there equivalent to `perl -c` syntax check for JavaScript from command? Given that I have NodeJS installed?

JSLint is not considered as it is not a real parser. I think YUI compressor is possible but I don't want to install Java on production machines, so I am checking if Node.JS already provided this syntax check mechanism.

Comment: Try uglify. You can install it via npm.

Comment: Install just java or anything? If only java you could check http://www.javascriptlint.com/

Comment: Shouldn't you check the syntax before pushing the project to production? Maybe even before committing?

Comment: @AaditMShah uglify work as expected, please make this as answer so I can close it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try <strike>uglify</strike>. You can install it via npm.

Edit: The package name has changed. It is **uglify-js**.

Comment: This may have changed. I get this error: npm ERR! 404 'uglify' is not in the npm registry.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to perform a syntax check like that way we do in perl ( another scripting language) you can simply use `node -c <js file-name>`

e.g. a JS file as `test.js` has:

```
let x = 30
if ( x == 30 ) {
  console.log("hello");
else {
  console.log( "world");
}
```

now type in `node -c test.js`
it will show you

```
test.js:5
 else {
 ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token else
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:11)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Now after fixing the syntax issue as

```
let x = 30
if ( x == 30 ) {
  console.log("hello");
} else {
  console.log( "world");
}
```

check syntax - `node -c test.js` will show no syntax error!!

**Note** - we can even use it to check syntax for all files in a dir. - `node -c *.js`

Comment: Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Just what I needed! Initially tried acorn and that wasn't working for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
nodejs --help
```

explains the -p switch: it evaluates the supplied code and prints the results.  So using `nodejs -p < /path/to/file.js` would be a disastrous way to check the validity of node.js code on your server. One possible solution is the one indicated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097761/in-node-js-how-do-you-check-whether-a-given-string-of-code-is-syntactically-cor) SO thread.  The one thing not so good about it - the syntax error messages it reports are not terribly helpful.  For instance, it tell you something is wrong but without telling you **where** it is wrong.

Comment: To be honest, I think you're correct. I think it's possible that when I posted my answer, the behaviour was correct for the version of node that I was running. Currently I use `js -C <file>` to syntax check JS files, it's been like that for a while. I've deleted my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately that makes this answer not make much sense. Sorry about that.

Comment: @pgl node -C <file>? Could you explain?  Is this for server-side JS syntax checking? Is this a command line option for V8js by any chance?

Comment: I didn't realise this initially, but It looks like the `js` I'm using isn't part of node itself. This is on CentOS, and the `yum provides /usr/bin/js` lists this package as the origin: `js-1.70-12.el6.x86_64`. (On Ubuntu, `/usr/bin/js` is just a symlink to `/usr/bin/node`.)

Comment: Also, just this is the output of `js --version`: `JavaScript-C 1.7.0 2007-10-03`.