# In node.js, How do you check whether a given string of code is syntactically correct in the most lightweight way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, eval

Imagine that I accept a piece of code from a user and want to just check whether the given string is a valid JS or not? Just from the syntax perspective.

```
function checkCode(x){
// Logic

}
// returns a boolean, whether 'x' is syntactically right or wrong.
```

I don't want solutions with **`eval`**, since the whole nodejs process gets in to a syntax error when the given code, 'x' is syntactically wrong.

Comment: This is easy, you shouldn't! Accepting code from a user and inserting it into your serverside codebase is probably one of the worst things you can do ?

Comment: As a sidenote, to check if the code is "runnable" you can just insert it into a try/catch block and catch any errors.

Comment: @adeneo Am afraid the Try/Catch block doesn't get me the Syntax errors?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: @adeneo About running user code in node.js server. Am aware of the exact problem you're talking about. The use case goes like this, get the JS code from the user and validate it for syntax errors and generate a new page which uses that JS code for client side. (This code is only served to a browser client and the intention is not to execute it dynamically in the server)

Comment: A headless browser comes to mind, if you have to make sure it actually runs, otherwise many syntax highlighters also checks for errors in the string of code etc.

Comment: If it's gonna run in the user's browser then you could just `eval` it there without round-tripping through the server. `try/catch` should catch the error. Doing it directly will also give feedback to the user quicker.

Comment: @Supr Oh Yeah ! I could possibly, Eval/Try/Catch in the browser itself, when I get it from the user. That will work. 

Now that I know the solution, what do I do with this question? Leave it there? No one answered below !

Comment: Even if the browser validates the javascript, do not send it to the server to be executed unless you don't care about security.

Comment: @Skeptical Never perform validation on the client. Though I suppose based on this question that there are bigger flaws in your security.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `eval` that is literally the same as handing over the control of your server to the public internet. Anyone can do anything with your server - delete files, leak files, send spam email and so on. I am shocked that the answer had received 3 upvotes by the time I noticed it.

Just use a Javascript parser like esprima http://esprima.org/

Here is a syntax validator example it can even collect multiple errors: https://github.com/ariya/esprima/blob/master/demo/validate.js#L21-L41

Answer (score 10):

To check a string contains syntactically valid JavaScript without executing it (which would be an incredibly bad idea), you don't need a library, you may use the parser you already have in your JS engine :

```
try {
     new Function(yourString);
     // yourString contains syntactically correct JavaScript
} catch(syntaxError) {
     // There's an error, you can even display the error to the user
}
```

Of course this can be done server side.

[Check this demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/upELG/)

Answer (score 2):

If it's gonna run in the user's browser then you could just eval it there without round-tripping through the server. `try/catch` should catch the error. Doing it directly will also give feedback to the user quicker.

I already had some code lying around after an experiment. I modified it slightly and put it in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tKM3L/).

Basically just use try/catch:

```
try {
    eval('Invalid source code');
} catch(e) {
    alert('Error: '+e)
}
```

Comment: Wtf? You are directly evaluating user input as code on server side!

Comment: @Esailija No I'm not. Read my original comment on the question: This is meant to run in the client browser, where security is not an issue since the user has full power to do anything anyway. Should have repeated that in the answer here though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try JSLint.

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint

It's a little bit heavy but it work well.

Comment: That does too much. There are plenty of tools that aren't so opinionated.

Comment: @BlueSkies This was my first idea. But you're certainly right.